# What is meant by “a process has open handles to system objects”?

Tags: process, memory

The following are qualities of a process:

```
virtual address space
executable code
open handles to system objects
a security context
a unique process identifier
environment variables
a priority class
minimum and maximum working set sizes
at least one thread of execution
```

What is meant by "a process has open handles to system objects"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an operating system that isn't a unix by any stretch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you get that list from here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681917(v=vs.85).aspx.

> Each process provides the resources needed to execute a program. A
>   process has a virtual address space, executable code, open handles to
>   system objects, a security context, a unique process identifier,
>   environment variables, a priority class, minimum and maximum working
>   set sizes, and at least one thread of execution. Each process is
>   started with a single thread, often called the primary thread, but can
>   create additional threads from any of its threads.

Here the term "handles" is meant to be a pointer. Processes have access to "system objects", and a handle is a programming construct where the process can request an officially "tracked" pointer, rather than just point into the Kernel's objects through memory accesses directly.

The advantage of doing this is that the kernel can then keep track of which processes are using which resources through the assignment of handles to its objects, for things like sharing or locking or these objects, for example.